# How can I configure multiple Quartz schedulers with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I need to have multiple schedulers, all clustered with JDBC datastore. Is it possible to configure them in the application.yaml?

I believe for one scheduler it would be like the following I found on the web.

```
spring:
    application.name: myApp
    quartz:
        properties:
            org:
                quartz:
                    scheduler:
                        instanceId: AUTO
                    threadPool:
                        threadCount: 5
                    plugin:
                        shutdownhook:
                            class: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
                            cleanShutdown: TRUE
                    jobStore:
                        class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
                        driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
                        tablePrefix: my_schema.
                        isClustered: true
                        dataSource: myDataSource
                    dataSource:
                        myDataSource:
                            driver: org.postgresql.Driver
                            URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDataSource
                            user: removed
                            password: removed
```

Can I specify multiple blocks like that with different names for each scheduler?

Comment: No, you would need manual configuration for that. But do you really need multiple schedulers is the question to ask. Why do you need multiple in the first place?

Comment: We have a large number of short running jobs (1 to 3 seconds), so, we see that the performance is really bad. That issue is explained in this article. https://foobot.io/resources/tech-blog/tuning-quartz-scheduler-for-large-number-of-small-jobs/
So, we are trying to add about 10 schedulers and allocate jobs across them in random manner.